# Need help adjust header img to right size

Tags: html, css

So I want to decrease the size of the img on the header so it looks cleaner and a more sharp img , however i am unsure how to do it?

Here is the code

CSS:

```
.header {
   background: #000000 url (C:/website/logo final.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 80px 60px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div id="header" align="center">
    <img name="Antique Picture" src="C:\website\logo.jpg
    " alt="logo" width="100%" height="100%">
    </header>
```

all help would be rly appreciated thankyou

Comment: the `align` attribute is deprecated, the `width` and `height` attributes need to be [pixels](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dimension-attributes) (without the `px`), you didn't close your `<div>`, and we can't see the image you're using so we can't give you feedback on how to resize it so it's "cleaner and more sharp"

Comment: can you set the `.header` overflow style? That might help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to tackle this one. As Michael Coker said, there are a number of flaws that need fixing in your HTML structure:

1) The align attribute is deprecated. We'll cover that with CSS.

2) Image widths must either be pixel-based, or covered in CSS.

3) The header `div` isn't closed.

4) You provided local images, so we can't access them, meaning we can't check if they're blurry.

Additionally, the `img` tag has no attribute `name`, and the background-image URL must have no space and quotes around the file path. I'll ignore the fact that it's bad practise to have a space in the filename, as it will work with the space.

Fixing up those problems, your new structure looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <div id="header">
    <img src="C:\website\logo.jpg" alt="logo">
  </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
  background: #000000 url('C:/website/logo final.svg') no-repeat;
  background-size: 80px 60px;
}
```

To centralise the header, you need to add `text-align: center` to it in the CSS:

```
.header {
  background: #000000 url('C:/website/logo final.svg') no-repeat;
  background-size: 80px 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

To adjust the image widths properly, you should use CSS for this as well:

```
.header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Keep in mind that percentage-based widths are relative to the **parent element**. The header parent element will need a height and width in order for the image child to adapt. If you'd prefer a **fixed** image width, these values should be specified in pixels:

```
.header img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Then if you find it is stretched, you can adjust the pixel values above (or the image itself, if that is easier).

Hope this helps!